# Differences between these power steering pressure hose options?

Tags: power-steering, parts, hose

These are 2 results from a search for `es300 power steering pressure hose` - on the **same** site, and by the **same** manufacturer.

[CARQUEST Power Steering 16MM Banjo x 16MM Female O-Ring](https://shop.advanceautoparts.com/p/carquest-power-steering-16mm-banjo-x-16mm-female-o-ring-36552/18071186-P)

[CARQUEST Power Steering 16MM Male O-Ring x 16MM Male O-Ring](https://shop.advanceautoparts.com/p/carquest-power-steering-16mm-male-o-ring-x-16mm-male-o-ring-36307/18070388-P)

The 'banjo' one is priced 2.5x of the other. How are they related, is the 2nd one just the inner pressure tube used inside the banjo model? In the case of a leaky pressure hose, do I just need the 2nd one if I want to provide parts for the repair work? *(note: I do not intend to do the labor myself, will be going to a local garage)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part you need depends on which hose is leaking. One hose is a solid hose (male-to-male connections) while the other hose is a flex hose (male-to-female connections). Figure out which one is leaking on your car and then purchase accordingly. The only way to do this is to look at what is leaking, then discover what that line is like, then match it to which ever hose you are seeing for sale. Looking at the pictures of the for sale items and the descriptions tells you what they are. Don't look at the price and think you can just get away with buying the cheaper hose. You need the hose you need (if you actually need a hose in the first place).

Comment: Aha, thanks - I thought both were the same. I probably need the banjo, as I looked into the engine area and decided it was the hose based on the fatter area (near bottom) looking wet & leaky. I do plan to ask garage to charge me just diagnostics fee if I'm wrong & its the pump instead.